# How best to store trading hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

I have a venues model, and wish to store trading hours within my Postgres db. I am trying to work out the best way to do this so that i can check if the time has passed on any given day and display that the venue is now closed. I was originally thinking it would be best to store this data as a string but figured it would be hard to compare to Time.now. Does anyone have any suggestions on how best to achieve this, and then also list the days out i.e. Monday 8.00am - 5.30pm, Tuesday 8.00am - 5.30pm etc..

Comment: Why don't you just use the PostgresSQL time type as per the [PostgresSQL Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html)? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You can list the time ranges in 4 digits integers. For example:

```
8:00am -> 800
8:30am -> 830
11:32  -> 1132
8:30pm -> 2030
```

In this way it's quite easy to perform queries based on time ranges or other filters.

As per the day of the week representation, you either create a time column for each week (aka 7 columns) or you create a separate model that represents a single day and it contains a column for the day of the week and the time and you attach them with a one-to-many relationship with the venues model.

The former is simpler but the latter is more flexible especially when you have to create more complex queries.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. What time is 890, 8933 or 9999?

Comment: @JohannesThorn if you end up with those values it means you have a problem in your app. That's not a fault of the database representation, it's a problem of the code not properly validating the input.

Comment: I would say it depends. Why rely on the code when you can solve the validation problem by using semantic SQL types.

Comment: There are plenty of real world problems that cannot be mapped into SQL types. Anyway, feel free to propose a different answer.